# I want to remove the first checkbox column from lightning data table in LWC. How I do that?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

This is the image of my datable, I am getting the first checkbox column by default but i don't want it.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you checked the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/specification)?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using **lightning-datatable**, you can use

> hide-checkbox-column="true"

to hide the first column.

Comment: You don't need ="true" part for hiding checkbox.